# Why one uses 了 and the other one doesn’t?

Tags: grammar

> 我每天吃吃睡睡，从来不运动，吃饱就睡，醒了，就吃，怎么还是不胖。

I wonder why the writer didn’t add 了 after “吃饱” whereas they added 了 after 醒.

I know what 了 indicates here, it’s just that I don’t know why the writer didn’t treat “吃饱就睡” and “醒了就吃” equally.

> 1) Is it for the sake of “even amount of characters (4 - 4)”?

Then...

> 2) Is it okay if I add 了 after 吃饱 > “吃饱(了)就睡”?

- One trivial question to add :

> A native once corrected me for not putting 都 after 每天, then why
>   doesn’t this one have 都 in it though?

Comment: some users might suggest it has sth. to do with 吃饱 consisting of verb followed by result complement while 腥 is a monosyllabic verb by itself, thus it seems to add clarity to add 了, it also seems 了 can be added after 吃饱

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall, your analysis is correct. It's indeed for the sake of “even amount of characters (4 - 4)” in this case. It might be more obvious if it writes: "吃饱就睡，醒了就吃" or "吃饱就睡，睡醒就吃".

吃饱了就睡 is also correct.

Answer (score 3):

了 is omitted to match the 4 syllables of the following sentence. 吃了就睡，醒了就吃 also works nice.